# Strange value in DNS shown in ipconfig

Tags: windows-7, internet, dns, ipconfig

If I run `ipconfig /all`, in the DNS field it is showing numbers such as `fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1`, `fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1` and `fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1`. `nslookup www.google.com` shows some kind of DNS error (lookup not found or similar). What does this mean and how do I fix it?

I didn't change any settings on my computer. I am supposed to be able to connect to the Internet as soon as I plug in the cable but this day the Internet stopped working for some reason. So when I checked `ipconfig` I saw those strange values.

This is what `ipconfig` shows about DNS:

[image]

Comment: [ipv6](http://www.opendns.com/technology/ipv6/)?

Comment: I would look at the network adapter settings and see if IPv6 is on but IPv4 is not. This is DNS related. You should still be able to ping addresses like 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.2. In which case, internet is actually working, just not DNS resolution.

Comment: Could you please try disabling ipv6 [here](http://support.microsoft.com/Library/Images/2635887.png)?

Comment: it sounds like there is moregoing on here. The list of things to check will be quite large and we don't have much to go on yet. Try some of the things listed here to start and try to narrow down the problem more. http://www.howtogeek.com/126265/how-to-troubleshoot-internet-connection-problems/

Comment: The DHCP server you are connecting to appears to be handing out IP6 DNS addresses. That's where your strange letters are coming from.

Comment: so it's more likely the problem is at the Internet provider's side then? Would it be possible for me to directly view websites by entering their ip address?

Comment: If it's just your DNS, then yes, you could get to Google via one of their addresses. http://74.125.227.129/ is one. If you cannot, then you have a connectivity issue.

Comment: I think that you should `nslookup` the root of the domain name like so: `nslookup google.com`. I don't have a windows machine to hand to test this though, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Somehow you have enabled IPv6 on your node. Those are default IPv6 "site local anycast" addresses for DNS that Microsoft configures automatically if no other IPv6 DNS addresses are configured. They are obsolete (site local was deprecated in 2004, [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Deprecated_and_obsolete_addresses_2)). See also the IETF draft [IPv6 Stateless DNS Discovery](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ipv6-dns-discovery-04).

They are kind of like link local (`fe80::`), but can cross internal routers (link local won't cross any router). Microsoft DNS servers will accept DNS connections to any of those addresses, so this allows IPv6 DNS to work without any additional configuration. Not all DNS servers accept these.

Anycast means you can have several servers all publish the same address, but only one will actually accept any given connection from a client (different from multicast and unicast). Anycast is something new in IPv6.

You probably aren't actually using IPv6, so I suggest you configure some IPv4 addresses for DNS. You may want to disable IPv6, although somehow your node thinks it is available to you. Perhaps your ISP has started routing it to you - most will be doing that sooner or later. You should start learning it now, as IPv4 is on the way out - within a couple of months all the major RIRs will be out of public IPv4 addresses - the only public addresses available will be IPv6 from then on (except in very limited number, for very high prices). All but ARIN (N. America) are already out - APNIC ran out back in early 2011.

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed using IPv6. This is the default address, something like the 169. addresses in IPv4 that Windows uses and indicates that you could not find a DHCP server when your machine requested a new address.

If you do an ipconfig /renew do you pick up a real address? 
Did you make changes recently to the networking configuration?
Is this a home or work network and are other clients on the same network still able to resolve?

Please post the entire contents of ipconfig /all

Comment: I reset the router and switch and that seems to have solved the problem. While it's working, it look s like the DNS is two ipv4 addresses. So now I am sure it has to be ipv4 to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this issue again I know this was posted years ago but my solution was that for some odd reason in the properties of IPv6 these addresses were listed in the "Use the following DNS server addresses:" section of the properties of the network adapter. I did not put them there and this was a fresh clone of a machine in ESXi that did not have these in there as well.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issues, and I will focus on how I fixed it but I don't know how it happened.

1. Disabled IPv6. This step may not be needed at all, but I tried doing step 2 on IPv6, and it didn't work. Maybe my gateway wasn't configured correctly for it.
2. Enabled IPv4 to retrieve DNS from my gateway (router). Previously, it was set to localhost 127.0.0.1

Both of these are done in the Adapter settings:
[image]

1. Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections
2. Right click on the Adapter and go to Properties
3. Disable IPv6
4. Got to the properties of IPv4
5. Select "Obtain DNS server address automatically"

NOTE: this solution depends on your Gateway being configured to provide DNS Servers. Alternatively, you could directly provide the DNS server address(es) here.

Click OK and close out the settings.

That's all I had to do and it refreshed my DNS Server from my gateway. To verify your DNS Server:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Maybe try `ipconfig /renew` if that didn't work, reboot, etc.

Answer (score -2):

I KNOW THE PROBLEM!

You have Hamachi downloaded am I not mistaken?
Your looking at the wrong part of the ipconfig! I just figured it out! Scroll up a litttle more to find your actual router config!

Comment: Thanks.  Don't know what's up with the downvotes... but it was true in my case

Comment: @Brett There are many programs that add virtual network adapters (VMWare and VirtualBox to name a few), yet this information doesn't help solve the actual problem.

Answer (score -4):

go to your advanced adapter settings through the network and sharing center. uninstall all protocols, services, and clients.  Then, install each group of them in this order:
protocol
service
client

then click 'diagnose'

the issue should resolve itself.